# How to take in number from text box and multiple by a Value

Tags: java, android, textbox, integer

Hey Im new to android developing and I was using the tutorial on the official android website to help me create an app. so far I've create a textbox and when you click on it. it simply opens another screen and returns my name. How would I take the input from the textbox as a number and multiply by another value.

Heres the code i have so far.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.discountprice2.DisplayMessageActivity$PlaceholderFragment" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>



</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.discountprice2.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edit_message"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/edit_message"
        android:inputType="text" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/edit_message"
        android:text="@string/calc"
        android:onClick="sendMessage"  />

</RelativeLayout>

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.example.myfirstapp.MESSAGE";

    public void sendMessage(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
        EditText editText=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
        TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);




        String message =editText.getText().toString();
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
        startActivity(intent);
        //get text from edittext and convert it to string
        String messageString=editText.getText().toString();

        //set string from edittext to textview
        textView.setText(messageString);

        //clear edittext after sending text to message
        //editText.setText("");


    }
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container,
                    false);
            return rootView;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: actually I'm not getting why all those people are just throwing code in your face, with a total disregard for the fact you are an android beginner. IMO, the official demo code is too complex and unclear for beginners, you should get some basic understanding for how android development works. Those tutorials are a good way to start with, I strongly suggest you to take a look https://buckysroom.org/videos.php?cat=77

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Frst, you must read in the value of the text field and save it to a string. Then, you must parse the text as a number and multiply it.

```
EditText field = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
String text = field.getText.toString();
double d = Double.parseDouble(text);
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the number is an integer, change your sendMessage method to this:

```
public void sendMessage(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
    EditText editText=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
    TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

    String message =editText.getText().toString();
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
    startActivity(intent);
    //get text from edittext and convert it to string
    String messageString=editText.getText().toString();

    int myNumber = Integer.parseInt(messageString);
    myNumber = myNumber*100; //this is where you multiply

    messageString = Integer.toString(myNumber);

    //set string from edittext to textview
    textView.setText(messageString);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you get from the `EditText` is String, you can change it to Integer like this:

```
 String message =editText.getText().toString();
 int intMessage = Integer.parseInt(message);
 int result = intMessage*10; //Now you can multiply with another value
```

Answer (score -1):

try this simple sample

```
String msg =editText.getText().toString();
```

`int intMsg = Integer.parseInt(msg);`

`int result = intMsg*10;`